# R, pairs(): Configuring the axes of subpanels when specifying lower/upper panels

Tags: r, plot

I use the lower.panel and upper.panel options to draw a `pairs()` plot of my data, and haven't figured out how and if its possible to configure the axes of the subpanels. E.g., if I use `data(iris)` , `pairs(iris[1:4],xlim=c(0,10))` gives me a plot where all x axes of the subplots are scaled from 0 to 10.

If I try `pairs(iris[1:4],xlim=c(0,10),lower.panel=panel.lm)`, it still works fine. As soon as I try the panel function `panel.cor` from the help file of `pairs()`, I get an error:

> unused argument (xlim = c(0, 10))

I've compared the codes for `panel.lm` and `panel.cor`, but am no further as to where I need to adjust a setting. Aside from setting `xlim` and `ylim`, it would be great to specify if axes should be labeled in the respective upper and lower panels, but I don't know if this is asking too much.

For reference, here are the two functions from the **R** help file:

```
panel.lm<-
function (x, y, col = par("col"), bg = NA, pch = par("pch"),
cex = 1, col.lm = "red", lwd=par("lwd"), ...)
{
points(x, y, pch = pch, col = col, bg = bg, cex = cex)
ok <- is.finite(x) & is.finite(y)
if (any(ok))
    abline(lm(y~x,subset=ok), col = col.lm, ...)
}
panel.cor <- function(x, y, digits=2, prefix="r = ", cex.cor)
{
usr <- par("usr"); on.exit(par(usr))
par(usr = c(0, 1, 0, 1))
r <- cor(x, y)
txt <- format(c(r, 0.123456789), digits=digits)[1]
txt <- paste(prefix, txt, sep="")
if(missing(cex.cor)) cex <- 0.8/strwidth(txt)
text(0.5, 0.5, txt, cex = cex * abs(r))
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just forgot to include the `...` in the `panel.cor` function. The only reason `xlim` works with `panel.lm` is that that argument is passed on to subsequent functions via `...`. Without the ellipsis, `panel.cor` sees an unknown argument, `xlim` and throws an error. Just change it to:

```
panel.cor <- function(x, y, digits=2, prefix="r = ", cex.cor,...)
```